# Bottom Navigation Bar is not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a flutter app and I'm using bottom navigation bar on this app. I wrote the code of the Bottom Navigation bar, in the separate dart page than import those page , where I want to show the bottom navigation bar. There is no error. But my problem is arise that My Bottom navigation bar is not showing in any page and not working properly.
bottom navigation bar code is:

> **bottom_navigation_bar.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/DewPoint.dart';
import 'package:my_app/MachineInfo.dart';
import 'package:my_app/MachinePage.dart';
import 'package:my_app/waterPage.dart';

class Nav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Nav> createState() {
    return _NavState();
  }
}

class _NavState extends State<Nav> { 
  int myCurrentIndex = 0;
  // List Pages = const[
  //   MachineStatus(),
  //   WaterGenerate(),
  //   // DewPoint(),
  //   // MachineInfo(),
  // ];
  List pages = const [
    MachineStatusPage(),
    waterPage(),
    DewPoint(),
    MachineInfo(),
    // MachinePage(),
    // WaterPage(),
    // DewPoint(),
    // MachineInfo(),
  ];
  // void onClicked(int index) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     myCurrentIndex = index;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Widget activePage = const MachineStatusPage();
    // if (_selectedPageIndex == 1){
    //   activePage = WaterGenaratePage();
    // }
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar:
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 40,),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black,
              blurRadius: 25,
            ),
          ]
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.amber,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          currentIndex: myCurrentIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              myCurrentIndex = index;
            });
          },
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem> [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.power),
            label: 'Status',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.water),
            label: 'Water',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.dew_point),
            label: 'Dew Point',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.info),
            label: 'Chassis Info',
          ),
        ],),
      ),
      body: pages[myCurrentIndex],
      // activePage,
    );
  }
}
```

than I import those page like: MachinePage, WaterPage, MachineInfo, DewPoint . Here I give only MachinePage's code for an example.
The code of the MachinePage is:

> **MachinePage.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:my_app/waterPage.dart';
import 'CompPage.dart';
import 'DewPoint.dart';
import 'MachineInfo.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class MachineStatusPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MachineStatusPage({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Nav(),
     
    );
  }
}
class MachinePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // const MachinePage({super.key});
  var machine;
  var nickname;
  MachinePage({Key? mykey, this.machine, this.nickname}) : super(key: mykey);
  @override
  State<MachinePage> createState() {
    return _MachinePageState();
  }

}
class _MachinePageState extends State<MachinePage> {

  var Version;
  var Comp;
  var Comp_Status;
  var arh;
  var adp;
  var temp;
  var status;

  var machine_id;
  bool loading = false;
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(220, 50, 99, 125),
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text('Machine Status'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.logout,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',))
                );
              },
            )
          ]
      ),
      // bottomNavigationBar: Nav(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 40,),
                    Text("Machine Id :  ${widget.machine}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,color: Colors.white, )),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Text("Nick Name : ${widget.nickname}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,color: Colors.white,)),
                    // Image(image:  new AssetImage("assets/images/mstatus.png")),
                    SizedBox(height: 80,),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('ON', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20,)),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(80),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue, // <-- Button color
                        foregroundColor: Colors.red, // <-- Splash color
                      ),
                    ),

                  ],
                  // ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          // Nav(),
        ],
      ),
      // bottomNavigationBar: Nav(),
      //   ),
      // ),
    );
  }

}
```

In **`MachinePage.dart`** , I declare the class of the **`bottom_nav_bar.dart`**.
but the bottom navigation bar is not visible and not worked properly . How I fix it.
[image]

Comment: can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: Sure. I added a screenshot. The Menu bar is not visible.

Comment: I reckon you don't need to have bottom nav widget in each of your pages.Your Nav page should be the root page which will handle the pages switch. see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Comment: maybe because you're importing a scaffold inside a scaffold? Do other type of widgets created in Nav show?

Comment: yes that is exactly the issue, you are making the bottomNavigationBar of your root scafold a scafold, so your actual bottomNavigationBar is at the bottom of the new scafold, just remove the scaffold on your Nav widget.

Comment: When I remove the scaffold on the Nav widget , I am getting error. Then what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code. Try to run it in https://dartpad.dev/

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: Nav(),
      );
    }
  }


  class Nav extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<Nav> createState() {
      return _NavState();
    }
  }

  class _NavState extends State<Nav> { 
    int myCurrentIndex = 0;
    // List Pages = const[
    //   MachineStatus(),
    //   WaterGenerate(),
    //   // DewPoint(),
    //   // MachineInfo(),
    // ];
    List pages = const [
      MachineStatusPage(),
      MachineStatusPage(),
      MachineStatusPage(),
      MachineStatusPage(),
      // MachinePage(),
      // WaterPage(),
      // DewPoint(),
      // MachineInfo(),
    ];
    // void onClicked(int index) {
    //   setState(() {
    //     myCurrentIndex = index;
    //   });
    // }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      // Widget activePage = const MachineStatusPage();
      // if (_selectedPageIndex == 1){
      //   activePage = WaterGenaratePage();
      // }
      return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar:
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 40,),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black,
                blurRadius: 25,
              ),
            ]
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.amber,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
            currentIndex: myCurrentIndex,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                myCurrentIndex = index;
              });
            },
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem> [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.power),
              label: 'Status',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.water),
              label: 'Water',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.dew_point),
              label: 'Dew Point',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.info),
              label: 'Chassis Info',
            ),
          ],),
        ),
        body: pages[myCurrentIndex],
        // activePage,
      );
    }
  }


  class MachineStatusPage extends StatelessWidget {
    const MachineStatusPage({super.key});

    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MachinePage(machine: 0011, nickname: "Home");
    }
  }
  class MachinePage extends StatefulWidget {
    // const MachinePage({super.key});
    var machine;
    var nickname;
    MachinePage({Key? mykey, this.machine, this.nickname}) : super(key: mykey);
    @override
    State<MachinePage> createState() {
      return _MachinePageState();
    }

  }
  class _MachinePageState extends State<MachinePage> {

    var Version;
    var Comp;
    var Comp_Status;
    var arh;
    var adp;
    var temp;
    var status;

    var machine_id;
    bool loading = false;
     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(220, 50, 99, 125),
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
            title: Text('Machine Status'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.logout,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
  //                 Navigator.pushReplacement(
  //                     context,
  //                     MaterialPageRoute(
  //                         builder: (context) => MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',))
  //                 );
                },
              )
            ]
        ),
        // bottomNavigationBar: Nav(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 40,),
                      Text("Machine Id :  ${widget.machine}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,color: Colors.white, )),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text("Nick Name : ${widget.nickname}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,color: Colors.white,)),
                      // Image(image:  new AssetImage("assets/images/mstatus.png")),
                      SizedBox(height: 80,),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('ON', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20,)),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: CircleBorder(),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(80),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue, // <-- Button color
                          foregroundColor: Colors.red, // <-- Splash color
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                    // ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            // Nav(),
          ],
        ),
        // bottomNavigationBar: Nav(),
        //   ),
        // ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95lop.png)
Is working!
The provided code executed successfully. Please review your log .

Comment: I review my log but the code not working properly like you. Can you share your code that I find and understand where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You are encountering an issue due to recursive calls between the `Nav` and `MachineStatusPage` widgets. To resolve this, consider setting `Nav` as the home widget and then embedding the page widgets within it, rather than invoking them directly within each other.

Answer (score 0):

@SalmanAhmed is right. The Navigation bar is in an infinite loop.

You are calling Nav from MachineStatusPage and the nav is calling Again MachineStatusPage and this loop continues.

I think you might wanna use MachinePage instead of MachineStatusPage. Did you just mistyped it to MachineStatusPage?

Try removing MachineStatusPage from the list or renaming it to MachinePage().
Like this:

```
List pages = const [
    MachinePage(),
    waterPage(),
    DewPoint(),
    MachineInfo(),
    // MachinePage(),
    // WaterPage(),
    // Dew Point(),
    // MachineInfo(),
  ];
```

Instead of:

```
List pages = const [
    MachineStatusPage(),
    waterPage(),
    DewPoint(),
    MachineInfo(),
    // MachinePage(),
    // WaterPage(),
    // DewPoint(),
    // MachineInfo(),
  ];
```